# Fast way to search through Google Drive in Chrome OS?

Tags: google-chrome-os, chromebook

In ChromeOS, is there a way to search through files in Google Drive without explicitly opening the Files app, and pressing search there? The search key on the keyboard seems to only trigger an online search, not within Google Drive.﻿

Comment: This is not a question about programming.

Comment: If you want to make your question about programming and more relevant to Stack Overflow then it may help you to point out the [REST API to Drive search](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/search-parameters) or [a Chrome extension in GitHub that suggests it implements Drive search](https://github.com/kissrobber/advanced_google_drive_search_chrome_extension).